# Help me identify this plant

Tags: identification

My mother just came back from a family trip and would like to purchase a plant like this one. Their owner didn't seem to know what this plant what, any help is most appreciated!

[image: plant in question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plant looks to be Stromanthe sanguinea 'triostar'. Family Marantaceae, along with calathea sp. Order ginger. From tropical south America. Cultivar sold by Monrovia in big box improvement stores in the gulf coast, mostly Florida. Zones 9-11. Prefers shade or part sun with moisture when outdoors. Used as indoor plant also.

http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/b/Marantaceae/none/none/cultivar/0/

Comment: You're right, this actually looks like a perfect match!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it could be something in the Aglaonema family, but your picture is so blurry it is difficult to be sure.  Aglaonemas are popular houseplants with a [wide variety of different colors and varigated patterns](https://www.google.com/search?q=Aglaonema&client=firefox-a&hs=mir&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=np&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=OwZhU_bfIsiIyAHe1IGQCA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1284&bih=630&dpr=1.25).

Okay, after discussion and thinking about it some more, this is my new best guess.  Some type of [variegated ginger](http://www.agristarts.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/plants.plantDetail/plant_id/7/typeID/34/index.htm).  There seem to be dozens of varieties, if not a hundred or more.

Here are some pictures of various variegated shell gingers. I think these are a fairly close match to the height, leaf structure, stem structure and variegation patterns.  Be aware that the actual colors of the leaves can vary a fair bit depending on how much sunlight the plant is getting.  If this isn't it, or close to it, I'm all out of guesses.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do you have any more pictures of the plant, perhaps a closer shot of how the leaves and stems fit together?  Also, did you notice any flowers or flower buds on the plant?

Comment: I will try to get a higher quality picture from my mom and post it back asap

Comment: Put a higher resolution / better angle / nonblurry image instead

Comment: I'm going to stick with Anglaonema.  The longer stems threw me for a bit, but apparently that's not unusual as the plant ages, and the tips can be cut back and rooted for new plants.  So, bonus!

Comment: The leaves look very different to me (those on my picture are long and pointy while the aglaonema's are much larger and rounded). Also the patterns are very diferent, on my picture there seem to be bits of pinks & bits of green in chunks on a single leaf while on the aglaonema it's either colored veins or colored border. Also the color doesn't fade on my picture (goes from pink to green flat over a line) while it's more of a gradient on the Google pictures.

Comment: I could very well be wrong.  That is just how it looks to me from the pictures.  Some of the aglaonemas do, however, have longer pointy leaves - this one for example.  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Starr_070906-8788_Aglaonema_commutatum.jpg

Comment: I went through all 21 species in the genus listed on wikipedia & tried each one on Google image, there were a few species that would be close in leaf shape, but none of them would match the coloring patterns. Also all the ones in the species that get substantially colored seem to be ranging from dark pink to deep red while the plant i pictured is a very light pink. I'm thinking it's not of this genus.

Comment: Yeah, I think now I'm not right on my first guess.  I'm updating my post to show my new best guess...

Comment: Did a quick search for Aglaonema red based on Teresa's answer and the picture. I think I found the exact plant. Aglaonema Red Sumatra. See http://www.gardenworld.in/44187c178_Aglaonema-Red-Sumatra.html

Comment: the leaf colour of the Red Sumatra aglonema is correct but the stems in the picture from the original poster are too thin.  It almost looks like a silk plant the stems are so straight and regular

Comment: Has anyone checked out the ginger family guess?  The stems and the leaves look right for ginger, and the variegation markings look more like it, too, but I haven't found a variegated ginger yet with the pink/red stripes.

Comment: Got 1 more information from my mom (would've been usefull if she said it earlier), the plant is actually pretty tall (doesn't show much in the picture since there aren't many objects to notice the scale), she said it's over 1.20meter (around 4 foot)

Comment: Just added some pictures of various variegated "Shell Gingers" to my original post.  If that's not it, I'm all out of guesses, sorry!

Comment: the color of 1 picture is right and the pattern of another one is too, i'll look up some more on Google images and see if i can find a shell Ginger that is close but yea, this looks closer

Comment: this does feel like a match (variegated shell Ginger, pink) http://www.google.fr/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.floridaflowerpower.com%2Fimage%2Fshadeplants%2Fginger-pink-varigated-shell.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.floridaflowerpower.com%2Fshade.htm&h=480&w=640&tbnid=1bRdaL6RETEmfM%3A&zoom=1&docid=XPC625dB26KryM&ei=Vt1iU4vjEsSX1AWqh4GACw&tbm=isch&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=281&page=6&start=278&ndsp=60&ved=0CKMCEK0DMF84yAE

Comment: The stems in the Q don't look like either ginger or aglaonema unless the middles of some stems were pruned off of a shell ginger. Hopefully there's a scientist out there somewhere trying to figure out how to genetically modify plants so they grow a QRCode under their leaves. :)

Comment: I also think your pink Shell Ginger is probably a good match. Shell ginger is most often kept as an outdoor plant - one kept indoors wouldn't be as brightly colored.   Hope you can find one for your mom!